# Expand Tool-Tip to reveal more content

Tags: jquery

I have an icon with a box above it with the words Hello. When you hover over the icon or the box I want it to expand and reveal text that is hidden (World on Hot Fiya!), much like a read more/read less function. The problem I'm having is, when the box reveals it covers the icon because it reveals down. I'm wondering what I can do so the icon stays put and the box reveals the text going up.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<div class="icon"><img src="icon.jpg"></div>
<div class="box">
  Hello
  <p>World on Hot Fiya</p>
</div>

$('.box p').addClass('is-hidden');

$('.box').hover(function() {
  $('.box p').removeClass('is-hidden').addClass('block');
}, function() {
  $('.box p').removeClass('block').addClass('is-hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

****Revised to include request from comment*** *

Here is a plug-in that I just wrote to dynamically set heights (based on their initial/auto heights) -

http://jsfiddle.net/jmsessink/CTvMe/8/

Call the function on DOM ready, like so -

```
$(function () {
    $('.box').tooltipSlider({tooltip:'.tool-tip', titleHeight:'20px'});
});
```

---

Like it is shown above, the object's params in this function, tooltipSlider, are -

```
.tooltipSlider(
    {
        tooltip: '(class that you want to be the tooltip)',
        titleHeight: '(initial height of tooltip above icon (non-hovered))px'
    }
);
```

Hope that covers it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I noticed that the box is hidden behind the image. How would I be able to allow the box to get taller rather then slide up from behind the box?

Comment: the actual height of the box changes in this version - http://jsfiddle.net/jmsessink/CTvMe/1/

Let me know if you need something entirely different, because I may just not be understanding your question fully at that point.

Comment: Is there anyway not to define a height and just let it be set to 'auto'?

Comment: not really.  I will update my answer with a plug-in that I wrote for you.  It will describe usage in more detail and will hopefully fix your entire issue.

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much! 100% what I was trying to do. @JSess, thank you!